# How to conveniently save a plain image in GIMP?

Tags: script, gimp, productivity, usability

Ever since the [move to first class image editing file formats](http://gui.gimp.org/index.php/Save_%2B_export_specification), it is always a pain when I am 100% sure I want to just crop one image and not care about it.

I have already copied it and don't want the program to be careful for me.

Is there any way to write a script and assign a keyboard shortcut in GIMP to:

1. Export as the original format
   (same as I already can do with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
2. Write to the same filename (<kbd>Enter</kbd>?)
3. Accept the same compression as the source (<kbd>Enter</kbd> again,
   assuming the dialog takes the source image compression into consideration. 
   If not, I don't think I care much about that one...)
4. Confirm overwrite (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
5. Allow me to close the image pane without annoying me
   with the "discard changes" option (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
   after closing the image <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,
   which I may not want to do just now)

I already know [the developers do not want to do this as a first class feature](http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/14339-hate-the-new-save-vs-export-behavior); beats me to why... that's why I am asking for a script: because pressing 20 keys in a mind-numbing way is getting ridiculous.

I think I can work a script myself, except for the "mark this as not changed" in step 5. It would be really nice if I could close the image at a later time (after that same-file-export) and not be bothered with the discard changes dialog, but I can't imagine how to achieve that specific step. Something like dirty buffers in VIM...?

Answer (score 2):

I found the [GIMP Saver Plugin](http://shallowsky.com/blog/gimp/saver.html) that does exactly that and a little more.

I mapped it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.  Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> just saves the plain image and I'm done!  perfect!  I left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to "Export as",
which is the only one I use anyway.

It is perfect for those times when you have to visually tweak a dozen JPEGs and you can't just use ImageMagick.

Comment: Yes - that is form Akkana Peck - when using the GIMP from scripts, it is indded a single call that has to be made (to gimp-file-save  - for backwards compatibility purposes internally that had not even changed the name to 'export') -- Akkana's plug-in can have some other niceties - like marking the image as "clean" so GIMP won't complain about it not being saved as an XCF onimage close, and so on.